# Javascript form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I understand that this is very stupid, but the code between  tags just doesn't work.

I have a simple HTML registration form. And the js-code makes a simple check is any input is empty.

```
function validate() 
{
    if (document.forms.registration.email.value == "")
    {
        alert("You must provide an email address.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.forms.registration.password1.value != document.forms.registration.password2.value)
    {
        alert("You must provide the same password twice");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!document.forms.registration.agreement.checked)
    {
        alert("You must agree to ours terms and conditions");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For some reason the browser kind of ignores this code and submits the form, even if it's empty.

**EDIT:**(Added based on OP comment)

```
<form action="process.php" id="registration" method="get" onsubmit="return.validate();">
        <!-- Other child elements of the form -->
</form>
```

Comment: Are you actually binding this function to your form's submission event?

Comment: Please show how you're using this function.

Comment: @meagar & Claudio Redi. For both of you. Here is how I am using this js-code: <pre><code><form action="process.php" id="registration" method="get" onsubmit="return.validate();"></code></pre>

Comment: You don't need the dot, just `return validate();`. Check for javascript errors in your debugging console.

Comment: :) I don't have "pre" and "code" tags in my original code. I wanted to add it here, in comments for stylistic reasons.

Comment: @user1499804: I half expected that but didn't want to take a chance, modified it again now :) By the way did you have a look at showdev's answer? did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Harry Well, there is an error in apache's error.log file, very strange error. "File does not exist: /home/Projects/favicon.ico". I don't have this file, indeed. But it shouldn't exist anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `onsubmit="return.validate();"` by `onsubmit="return validate();"`.
As @showdev did say :

> You don't need the dot.

You could also use a javascript library such as [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) to produce your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! I am studying web development by Harvard's CS-75 course. And this code I wrote is from example. I was really stupid because the right version was written even in the example. So, really thank you. By the way, why did apache give me an error like this? I mean favicon.ico.